# How to select the close value in vector in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group

I would like to find the group in vector according the close value, like this:

```
    x <- c(1.001, 1.002, 1.003, 2.0)
```

and then calculate the mean of group [c(1.001, 1.002, 1.003)] which diff value < 0.1

```
    result <- c(1.002,1.002,1.002,2)
```

Thanks!
hees

Comment: Hi Roland, it is mass spectra data, i just want combine the close mz value, i guess we can sort the vector and then calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is  a solution that also handles unordered vectors:

```
x <- c(1.001, 1.002, 2.0, 1.003, 2.01, 3)
o <- order(x)
y <- x[o]
g <- cumsum(c(0, diff(y)) >= 0.1)
res <- tapply(y, g, mean)[as.character(g)]
res[o]
#    0     0     1     0     1     2 
#1.002 1.002 2.005 1.002 2.005 3.000
```

**Edit:**

> for example, i use the test data [x <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5, 1.6)], i want to get the closed value within 0.3, your code will give one group, all value is 1.35. actually, i want to have two group , one is 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4, another is 1.5, 1.6. and then calculate the mean value for each group.

Here is a quick solution using a `for` loop. It assumes that `x` is sorted. If it is too slow, it would be trivial to implement with Rcpp.

```
x <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5, 1.6)

d <- 0.3

s <- x[1]

g <- numeric(length(x))
g[1] <- 1

for (i in seq_along(x[-1]) + 1) {
  g[i] <- if (x[i] - s <= d) {
    g[i - 1] 
  } else {
    s <- x[i]
    g[i - 1] + 1
  }
}

tapply(x, g, mean)[as.character(g)]
#   1    1    1    1    2    2 
#1.25 1.25 1.25 1.25 1.55 1.55
```

Comment: Hi Roland, there is question. is it possible to handle the ordered vectors, we can combine the close value start the first one? the function cut() seems to being used?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please rephrase.

Comment: for example, i use the test data [x <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5, 1.6)], i want to get the closed value within 0.3,  your code will give one group, all value  is 1.35. actually, i want to have two group , one is 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4, another is 1.5, 1.6. and then calculate the mean value for each group.  thanks @Roland

Comment: See the edit ...